# Can't give back manager.list in Python multiprocessing from subprocess comes from array.tolist()

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, tolist

I would like to change a manager.list in a multiprocessing subprocess with via array(a).tolist(). Appending the list in subprocess works but changing with that method doesn't.

Any hint what is wrong? Thank you very much.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import numpy as np

def f(lst, lst1):
    lst.append([2])
    a = np.array([[8],[9]])
    lst1 = np.array(a).tolist()
    print('lst1: ', lst1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    manager = Manager()

    lst = manager.list()
    lst.append([1])
    print('lst main before: ', lst)

    lst1 = manager.list()
    lst1.append([7])
    print('lst1 main before: ', lst1)

    p = Process(target=f, args=(lst,lst1))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print('lst main after: ', lst)
    print('lst1 main after: ', lst1)
```

Output:

```
lst main before:  [[1]]
lst1 main before:  [[7]]
lst1:  [[8], [9]]
lst main after:  [[1], [2]]
lst1 main after:  [[7]]
```

Comment: `np.ndarray.tolist` creates a `list`, not a `manager.list` I'm not really sure what you were expecting here

Comment: Because lst1 is defined as manager.list in main I hoped that changes of lst1 in function def f changes lst1 in main. It works with append in lst. Obviously not... is there a way how I can give back the array or list in process to main?

Comment: `lst1 = np.array(a).tolist()` is never going to change the managed list. Variable assignment isn't a data copy in Python. You've just changed what object the `lst1` local variable refers to.

Answer (score 1):

A function parameter itself is a local variable to the function.

So, in `def f(lst, lst1):` you're defining two new variables called `lst` and `lst1` that get assigned the values you call the function with. Naming the variables the same as the variables you pass in doesn't affect that. In fact, good Python editors like PyCharm will warn you when you're doing this, you are 'shadowing' the global.

If you were to modify the list assigned to `lst1`, this will change the list that the global points to (it's the same list), but if you assign something new to `lst1`, it no longer points to that list and you won't see the change on the global variable.

For example:

```
def change_and_assign(xs):
    # adds 'b' to the list pointed to by local xs, but also global; it's the same list
    xs.append('b')
    # assigns a new list to the local, but doesn't modify global xs
    xs = ['c']

xs = ['a']
change_and_assign(xs)
print(xs)
```

This will print `['a', 'b']`, not `['c']`.

You should either return the value you're after, or assign it to a global that isn't shadowed (but I'd recommend the prior):

```
def change_and_return_new(xs):
    # same as before
    xs.append('b')
    # function will return the value and return value can be assigned
    return ['c']

xs = ['a']
# assign return value to ys
ys = change_and_return_new(xs)
print(xs, ys)

def change_and_assign_global(xs):
    # declare that zs should be a global
    global zs
    # same as before
    xs.append('b')
    # assign a new list to the global zs
    zs = ['c']

xs = ['a']
# this will modify xs, but also create a global zs
change_and_assign_global(xs)
print(xs, zs)
```

If you don't understand what's going on, reread and see if you get it, or look up some other information on global and local variables and scope - it's essential to get if you want to write Python code yourself without hard to track down bugs.

Comment: Thanks, variables are changed. Still does not work. Problem is I think  that with  lst1 = np.array(a).tolist() a new list is created (like written before) but I would like to access the existing list in main, what works with append...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying - you misread or perhaps I wasn't clear enough, naming of the variables doesn't mean a thing here. If you want to use a new value from inside a function, you have to either return the value or assign it to a global that has been declared as a global - the prior being vastly preferable over the latter.

Comment: As far as I've understood using global is not recommended and return does (and did) not work with multiprocessing, so the recommendation instead was using shared variables. But the object-concept was not fully clear (and maybe still it's not...) - appending changes an existing object and lst1= produces a new one in def. Thanks Grismar, a little bit more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, answer was already in the code and so easy, sorry to ask:

```
a = np.array([[8],[9]])
lst2 = np.array(a).tolist()
L1.append(lst2)
```

instead of:

```
a = np.array([[8],[9]])
lst1 = np.array(a).tolist()
```

Comment: Wasn't the issue that you weren't actually returning the values?

Comment: No, sorry, to be unclear before, my issue was that changes in the subprocess-list  didn't effect the - as I thought same - list in the main process. But as I've understood now 'lst1=' produces a new object and 'appending' changes an existing one.